# Convert digit to words in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

For one of my SSRS report, I need to show the numbers in letters:
e.g.

```
1 - ONE
23 - TWENTY THREE
6001233 - SIX MILLION ONE THOUSAND TWO HUNDRED THIRTY THREE
```

Is there any existing function in SQL Server which does that?

I have gone through the other answers and it talks about same old method of writing a big code foe that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know of no such built in function in SQL Server.  And I would rather handle this in the app layer.

Comment: Those of you who marked this as a duplicate seem to miss the fact that the @Nishant mentioned that he's using an SSRS report. Therefore, SSRS Custom Code (written in VB.NET as a single class) can be used to solve the problem. Here's a link to help: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18894.how-to-get-the-textual-representation-of-a-number-convert-number-to-words-in-vb-net.aspx.